# No build.json file found in Visual Studio Ionic project

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for my Ionic project. I'm trying to make a release build, but as I don't seem to have build.json file, I can't seem to make an automated release build, following the instructions here: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-android-version-of-your-app under the heading Create a signed package for projects that use Cordova CLI versions greater than 5.0 (I'm using 5.3.3).

On the flip side, I've generated my own build.json file but I have no idea how to include to be built in the project.

Any suggestions would be great, I can manually create a release build but it would be nice to have it done this way too :)

Cheers,

Rhys

Comment: can you show me your custom Build.json , ??

Comment: It's taken pretty much exactly from the link, save for my apps details.      {
 "android": {
     "release": {
         "keystore":"c:\\my-release-key.keystore",
     "storePassword":"pwd123",
     "alias":"johnS",
   "password":"pwd123",
           "keystoreType":""
       }
   }
}

Comment: it looks good what is your problem u are facing?

Comment: I've just realised my mistake. When I read "Build your app for the release configuration." I simply selected build from the build menu, when in fact there is a solution configurations drop down menu which has a 'release' setting. Although this seems painfully obvious now, Microsoft's documentation seems a bit misleading as I still had to create the build.json file from scratch (which they don't specify) and also they don't really specify that the release configuration is something you need to set. If you would like to make a post including everything in this comment, I will accept your answer.

Comment: i want add one more thing, build.json wil be there by default for newly creating .If its got missed , you need to add only if you are going for a release version then you need it, and i want to make another note that for ios you add to the same build.json , this contain the path to the Certificate and Provision file. and i am assuming before you adding to build.json, you have filled the ant.properties right

Comment: It is strange that it is missing considering I used VS to start a new project following the guide: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/, but yes I will accept that it can go missing and it needs to be added manually for release mode. I didn't know you could use build.json for iOS as it isn't stated: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-android-version-of-your-app either? I have not edited the ant.properties as the link directly above only states it necessary for "projects that use Cordova CLI versions less than 5.0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rhys Suggested here are points to be Noted while Building

1.Build.json is used when you are building for the Release. (You may need to manually generate this file if it doesn't exist by default) By using this format:

```
   {
     "android": {
         "release": {
        "keystore":"YourKeystore.jks",
        "storePassword":"YourStorePassword",
        "alias":"YourAlias",
       "password":"YourPassword",
        "keystoreType":""
           }
       }
    }
```

2. Start the build, for this there is a configurations drop down menu (next to the platform) which has a 'release' setting.

See this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChKsq.png) for highlighted release setting described above